# Software that generates a 3D Building Model from a 2D Image

Tags: 3d, image

I'm looking for a software which generates a 3D Building Model from an input image.

The software required must at least generate the façade of a building.

I know there are many great architecture design software out there such as *AutoCAD*, *GrassHopper*, *Rhino*, *Design Plan Home Design Software*, *3D Home Design Software*, *SketchUp*, *Sweet Home 3D* and *Graphisoft* but was wondering if any of these could achieve this.

If you're reading this and think that such a software does not exist please also comment to let me know.

Looking forward for your replies.
Thanks